# filter list of dicts to get lowest price

Tags: python

I have the following function that removes "semi duplicate" dictionaries from a list (only keeping one dictionary of them) based on "Price" and "Stock". The current code I have gets the lowest price for item in stock,However, I want to improve upon it to get the lowest item if all "semi duplicate" are out of stock,i.e get item with lowest price (priority for items in stock always even at higher price,else lowest price for item out of stock)

```
my_list=[{"Product Name":"x","Merchant_1_Price":"33","Merchant_1_Stock":True,"Seller":"y"},
{"Product Name":"x","Merchant_1_Price":"25","Merchant_1_Stock":False,"Seller":"y1"},
{"Product Name":"x","Merchant_1_Price":"32","Merchant_1_Stock":True,"Seller":"y1"},
{"Product Name":"x","Merchant_1_Price":"42","Merchant_1_Stock":True,"Seller":"y2"},
{"Product Name":"x1","Merchant_1_Price":"100","Merchant_1_Stock":True,"Seller":"z1"},...
]
by_asin = {}
for item in my_list:
    if item['Merchant_1_Stock'] == False:
        continue
    asin = item['Product Name']
    if (
        asin not in by_asin or
        float(item['Merchant_1_Price']) < float(by_asin[asin]['Merchant_1_Price'])
    ):
        by_asin[asin] = item
deduplicated_list_of_dicts = list(by_asin.values())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min(..)` here. As key you take a 2-tuple: first the negation of `Merchant_1_Stock`, and then the `Merchant_1_Price`, like:

```
min(my_list, key=lambda e: (not e['Merchant_1_Stock'], float(e['Merchant_1_Price'])))
```

For your given sample data, the result is:

```
>>> min(my_list, key=lambda e: (not e['Merchant_1_Stock'], float(e['Merchant_1_Price'])))
{'Product Name': 'x', 'Merchant_1_Price': '32', 'Merchant_1_Stock': True, 'Seller': 'y1'}
```

Python sorts tuples in *lexicographical* order. So that means that it considers `(x1, x2) ≤ (y1, y2)` given `x1< y1`; or `x2≤ y2`.

Since `False` is smaller than `True`, this thus means that we see items `e` with `e['Merchant_1_Stock']` as `True` as smaller here than if that was `False`. In case multiple items have `e['Merchant_1_Stock']` as `True`, we will order by the `e['Merchant_1_Price']`.

You can use this logic for example to obtain the **cheapest per item**. We can first use a `defaultdict` to group these per item, and then obtain the minimum. Like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

products = defaultdict(list)
for item in my_list:
    products[item['Product Name']].append(item)

result = {
    k: min(vs, key=lambda e: (not e['Merchant_1_Stock'], float(e['Merchant_1_Price'])))
    for k, vs in products.items()
}
list(result.values())
```

This then yields:

```
>>> {
...     k: min(vs, key=lambda e: (not e['Merchant_1_Stock'], float(e['Merchant_1_Price'])))
...     for k, vs in products.items()
... }
{'x': {'Product Name': 'x', 'Merchant_1_Price': '32', 'Merchant_1_Stock': True, 'Seller': 'y1'}, 'x1': {'Product Name': 'x1', 'Merchant_1_Price': '100', 'Merchant_1_Stock': True, 'Seller': 'z1'}}
```

or for the values:

```
>>> list(result.values())
[{'Product Name': 'x', 'Merchant_1_Price': '32', 'Merchant_1_Stock': True, 'Seller': 'y1'}, {'Product Name': 'x1', 'Merchant_1_Price': '100', 'Merchant_1_Stock': True, 'Seller': 'z1'}]
```

Comment: I believe you need to `float` Merchant_1_Price to make fair comparison of price correct?

Comment: @hadesfv: yes, I did not notice it was a string. Will update.

Comment: Also I believe this assumes that my_list contains one 'Product_Name", I need to do this on a list of dicts (unordered,different product names)

Comment: @hadesfv: so you want one *per* product name?

Comment: Yes,exactly one item for each product name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197893/discussion-between-hadesfv-and-willem-van-onsem).